# FCM notification isn't received in the terminated state

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I'm using `fcm` to get notifications in my flutter app. It works as expected in the foreground & background states but it doesn't in the terminated one. It's supposed that if I click on it, it takes me to a particular screen. But instead, the app routes to the main one, which I don't want. When I tried to fix this, it now doesn't get received at all no matter how much I tried. Please help me!
This is the complete stuff related to firebase messaging, I'm calling `initializeNotifications()` from the main function

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'main.dart';
import 'presentation/views/download/download.dart';

BuildContext context = navigatorKey.currentContext!;
final firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
const androidChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel',
  'High Importance Notifications',
  description: 'This channel is used for important notifications',
  importance: Importance.defaultImportance,
);
final localNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) async {
  if (message == null) {
    return;
  }
  String path = message.data['report_path'] as String ?? '';
  if (path.isNotEmpty) {
    //TODO: doesn't work in terminated case
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(DownloadScreen.routeName, arguments: path);
  }
}

void handleNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  String? payload = notificationResponse.payload;
  if (payload != null) {
    final message = RemoteMessage.fromMap(jsonDecode(payload));
    handleMessage(message);
  }
}

class FirebaseMessagingConfiguration {
  Future initializePushNotifications() async {
    //for apple
    await firebaseMessaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    //open the app from a terminated state via message
    firebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
    //open the app from a background state via message
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
    //handle the message from a terminated/background state
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleMessage);
    //handle the message (payload) in the foreground state
    //FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      final notification = message.notification;
      if (notification == null) {
        return;
      }
      localNotifications.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            androidChannel.id,
            androidChannel.name,
            channelDescription: androidChannel.description,
            icon: '@drawable/ic_launcher',
          ),
        ),
        payload: jsonEncode(message.toMap()),
      );
    });
  }

  Future initializeLocalNotifications() async {
    await localNotifications.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    //TODO: check iOS
    const ios = DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestSoundPermission: false,
    );
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launcher');
    const settings = InitializationSettings(
      android: android,
      iOS: ios,
    );
    await localNotifications.initialize(
      settings,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: handleNotificationResponse,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: handleNotificationResponse,
    );
    final androidPlatform =
        localNotifications.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
    await androidPlatform?.createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);
    //TODO: check/complete this
    /*final iosPlatform =
        localNotifications.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
    await iosPlatform?.initialize(ios);*/
  }

  Future<void> initializeNotifications() async {
    await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    await initializePushNotifications();
    await initializeLocalNotifications();

    await firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value) {
      print('TOKEN: $value');
    });
  }
}
```